# I can't use vendor package in yii2 - Class not found

Tags: php, api, yii2, mailer

I have a yii project and i would like get groups via mailerlite api.
I cant use package after composer update.

Do you need a conversion within the package?

Thank you for your help.

Sample code:

```
use MailerLiteApi\MailerLite;
public function actionTeszt() {
    $groupsApi = (new MailerLite('XXXXXXX'))->groups();
    $allGroups = $groupsApi->get();
    print_r($allGroups);
    exit;
}
```

Error
Class 'MailerLiteApi\MailerLite' not found

Comment: did you installed it via composer ? by adding the package name in the `composer.json` and then running `composer update`

Comment: of course and success download

Comment: add the complete error trace in that case as the given code does not give any hint or any problem

Comment: https://imgur.com/S70UXao
https://imgur.com/KSx5aPX

Comment: Please update your answer and add the error message! Do not use images that may not last forever. Also, the image content cannot be crawled by search engines.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
composer require mailerlite/mailerlite-api-v2-php-sdk && composer update
```

Comment: yes, the download was successful, i can see the package in the vendor folder

Comment: That's strange. Are you using the standard autoload functionality or has it been customized?